# Twitter Oauth authorization code

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

I am building a REST API.
For registering a user, he needs to authenticate on Twitter.

Normally, I would use an Authorization code provided by an OAuth2 server but it seems like Twitter does not implement this type of authorization.
I don't want my mobile app to send the Twitter token to the API to register  the user. I see this as a security flaw.

I checked OAuth echo (https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/echo) which seems okay. The user passes the credentials to my API, and my API checks the user against the twitter API. Twitter then returns a user object. It does not return a access token though.

Is it the only way to do this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. Using `OAuth Echo` will use you as the third party for that individual without exposing your Access token/key and Credentials.

Just be aware that you're under a different [rate limit](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits) from Twitter's API when you're going through that route. In some cases it's an increase in limit while it's a decrease in other.